# Программа вычисления суммы N целых чисел просто прибавляет единицу

Tags: c++, математика, циклы, ряды

Нужно написать программу, которая вычисляет сумму первых N целых положительных чисел.

Моя программа просто прибавляет к любому числу единицу. Помогите понять что не так. С++ только начал изучать.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int i, n, sum = 0;

    cout << "Введите число: " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++);
    {
        sum += i;
    }

    cout << "Сумма: " << sum << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если бы вы включили предупреждения компилятора, он вам скорее всего показал бы на эту `;`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Не поверите - но VC++ не показывает :)

Comment: Ваша задача требует одно, вы же пытаетесь сделать совершенно другое

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++);
```

последняя точка с запятой тут явно лишняя...

Впрочем, по большому счету тут лишний весь цикл -

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    unsigned int n;
    cout << "Введите число: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Сумма: " << n*(n+1)/2 << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

дает точно те же результаты...

Comment: А где соблюдается условие суммы именно положительных чисел?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Логично. `unsigned int n;` будет правильнее...

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам нужен такой код:

```
int i = 1, n, sum = 0, N;
cout << "Введите количество чисел: \n";
cin >> N;
cout << "Введите числа: " << endl;
while ( cin >> n && i <= N)
{
    if (n > 0) {
        sum += n;
        ++i;
    }
}
cout << "Сумма: " << sum << endl;
```

Comment: ТС говорит - программу, которая вычисляет сумму первых N целых положительных чисел. А не сумму первых N введенных.